# "SSL connect error" conectando con Proxies usando libcurl y C++, ¿Un poco de ayuda?

Tags: c++, c, curl, https

Quería comprabar una lista enorme de proxies que tengo porque solo me interesan los que usen el protocolo https (SSL) y los que no sean de China. Buscando una forma rápida de hacerlo di con esta función.

```
string proxyWorks(string ip, int port, string proxytype="")
{

    CURL *ch;
    CURLcode res;
    ch = curl_easy_init();

    if(!ch)
    return "chfail";


    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)2011-09-08 13:55:49");


    if(proxytype=="http")
        curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);

    if(proxytype=="socks4")
        curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4);

    if(proxytype=="socks4a")
        curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A);

    if(proxytype=="socks5")
        curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);

    if(proxytype=="https")
        curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTPS);



    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, ip.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, port);
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);


    res = curl_easy_perform(ch);
    curl_easy_cleanup(ch);

    if(res == CURLE_OK)
    {
        if(sizeof(buffer)>0)
            return "ok";
        else return "fail";
    }
    else
    return curl_easy_strerror(res);

}
```

Primero probé un par de IPs en una web para comprobar el resultado que tendría que darme. Esta web (https://hidemy.name/es/proxy-checker/), que por cierto si se preguntarán que porqué no hago todo en esa web es porque tengo un par de miles de proxies y esa web solo me deja poner 100 como máximo en cada vez.

Volviendo al tema, resulta que:

Si proxytype="" y en todos los casos tengo una sálida positiva (OK)

Si proxytype="http" también tengo una sálida positiva (OK)

Pero si proxytype="https" tengo una sálida negativa, para ser mas preciso la función **curl_easy_strerror(res)** me retorna el mensaje siguiente **SSL connect error**. (Según la web ese proxy si acepta el protocolo HTTPS).

El resto de los casos no me interesan así que no los he probado.

He probado a poner "https://google.com/"  en vez de "http://google.com/" pero funciona peor, es decir que no obtengo ningún caso positivo.

Debo añadir que es la primera vez que uso libcurl así que ese es mi nivel ahora mismo con esta libreria (Novato) :-)

Pues eso, en realidad tengo dos preguntas:

1º-¿Alguien sabe por qué está fallando con las conexiones HTTPS?

2º-¿Podría usar también esta libreria para filtrar las IP por paises y eliminar las chinas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

visto que nadie me ha contestado voy a contestarme a mi mismo ya que he encontrado una solución y a lo mejor a otro le es útil. Pues eso para saber los que soportan el protocolo HTTPS y con certificado se puede hacer con esta función.

```
string proxyWorks(string ip, int port)
{
    CURLcode res;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(!curl)
    return "chfail";


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com");    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, ip.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, port);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);


    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res == CURLE_OK)
    {
        if(sizeof(buffer)>0)
            return "ok";
        else return "fail";
    }
    else
    return curl_easy_strerror(res);

}
```

¿Alguien me ayuda a filtrar los proxy de China? :-)

Además me ha surgido otro problema y es que algunos proxies tienen filtros (fortinet) que no te dejan conectar a algunas webs... me gustaría poder descartar los proxies que usen esos filtros tambien. Basicamente sería comprobar si se puede conectar a esa web através de ese proxy. ¿Alguien sabe como hecerlo?

Comment: para filtrar por localización podes usar la libreria de maxmind https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb

Comment: Muchas Gracias **Alo!!**, le doy un vistazo a esa libreria.